# Ask about use coreference single in StanfordNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I want use Stanford NLP coreference sinle. Thats mean I done tokenizer and sentence spiliter and all of work need befor coref. I construct Document anotation and done all of anotation on it.
but when we want use coref it has error becuase I dont use of StanfordcoreNLP Class
it's my code:

```
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation document=new edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation(doc.toString());
    Properties props = new Properties();
    ArrayList <edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel> tokenAnnotate=new ArrayList<>();
    //document.set(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class,doc.toString());
    int countToken=0;
    int countSentence=0;
    for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        ArrayList <edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel> tokenAnnotateCoreMap=new ArrayList<>();
        // traversing the words in the current sentence
        // a CoreLabel is a CoreMap with additional token-specific methods
        edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap stanfordCorMap=new edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation(sentence.toString());
        int countFirstToken=countToken;
        for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(com.mobin.tp.textAnnotator.common.dto.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            // this is the text of the token
            countToken++;
            edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel coreLabel=mobinStanfordConverter.mobinToStanfordCorelabelConvertor(token);
            tokenAnnotateCoreMap.add(coreLabel);
            tokenAnnotate.add(coreLabel);
        }
        stanfordCorMap.set(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class,tokenAnnotateCoreMap);
        stanfordCorMap.set(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokenBeginAnnotation.class,countFirstToken);
        stanfordCorMap.set(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokenEndAnnotation.class,countToken);
        stanfordCorMap.set(CoreAnnotations.SentenceIndexAnnotation.class,countSentence);
        stanfordsnetence.add(stanfordCorMap);
        countSentence++;
        // this is the parse tree of the current sentence
        //Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
        // this is the Stanford dependency graph of the current sentence
        //SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.CollapsedCCProcessedDependenciesAnnotation.class);
    }

    document.set(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class,tokenAnnotate);
    document.set(edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class,stanfordsnetence);

    Annotator annotator=new ParserAnnotator(false,0);

    annotator.annotate(document);
    annotator=new DeterministicCorefAnnotator(props);
    annotator.annotate(document);
```

and this is my :
ERROR:

```
attempted to fetch annotator "parse" before the annotator pool was created!

java.lang.AssertionError
at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.getParser(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:345)
at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.parse(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:338)
at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.findSyntacticHead(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:273)
at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.findHead(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:215)
at edu.stanford.nlp.dcoref.RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.extractPredictedMentions(RuleBasedCorefMentionFinder.java:88)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.DeterministicCorefAnnotator.annotate(DeterministicCorefAnnotator.java:89)
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, standford's NLP library use Multi-Pass Sieve algorithm for resolving coreference. you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572207/stanford-core-nlp-understanding-coreference-resolution) to see how to use that library and this [javadoc](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/) for the complete documentation.

here's my code to test the result:

```
public class CoReferenceAnalyzer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

        String text = "My horse, whom I call Steve, is my best friend. He comforts me when I ride him";
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(document);

        Map<Integer, CorefChain> graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);
        System.out.println("Graph: " + graph.toString());
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, CorefChain> entry : graph.entrySet())
        {
            CorefChain chain = entry.getValue();
            CorefMention repMention = chain.getRepresentativeMention();
            System.out.println("Chain: " + chain.toString());
            System.out.println("Rep: " + repMention.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see the output like this:

```
Graph: {1=CHAIN1-["Steve" in sentence 1, "He" in sentence 2, "him" in sentence 2], 2=CHAIN2-["My horse , whom I call Steve" in sentence 1], 3=CHAIN3-["My horse" in sentence 1], 4=CHAIN4-["My" in sentence 1, "I" in sentence 1, "my" in sentence 1, "me" in sentence 2, "I" in sentence 2], 6=CHAIN6-["my best friend" in sentence 1], 8=CHAIN8-["He comforts me when I ride him" in sentence 2]}
Chain: CHAIN1-["Steve" in sentence 1, "He" in sentence 2, "him" in sentence 2]
Rep: "Steve" in sentence 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have encoutered the same question with you.
The problem maybe is that the maven released jar is not the same with the source code in **edu.stanford.nlp.simple.Document.java** on the same version 3.6.0.

In source code, the constructor of Document looks like this:

```
  public Document(String text) {
    StanfordCoreNLP.getDefaultAnnotatorPool(EMPTY_PROPS, new AnnotatorImplementations());  // cache the annotator pool
    this.impl = CoreNLPProtos.Document.newBuilder().setText(text);
  }
```

But in the maven jar code ,it looks like this:

```
  public Document(String text) {
    this.impl = CoreNLPProtos.Document.newBuilder().setText(text);
  }
```

the difference is very obvious.

so the method to solve the problem above is downloading the source code from
https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP and use ANT to make a new jar named **stanford-corenlp.jar**.
Then replace the old jar with the new one.

Hoping the method works for you.