# Does Stanford NER detect duplicate Entity mentions?

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp

Let’s take an example of a text: “***Barack Obama*** is an American politician serving as the 44th President of the United States. Born in Honolulu, Hawaii, ***Obama*** is a graduate of Columbia University and Harvard Law School.”

Below screenshot is how the 4 class NER model tags the entities:
[Result from Stanford NER Online Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GyTB.jpg)

Does Stanford NER detect that ***Barack Obama*** in line 1 is the same entity as ***Obama*** in line 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is called coreference resolution and yes,StanfordNLP has coreference resolution system.

you can refer to [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml)

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572207/stanford-core-nlp-understanding-coreference-resolution) to understand it clearly.

hope this helps!