# Coreference Resolution by CoreNLP CorefChainAnnotation.class not working

Tags: parsing, semantic-web, text-mining, stanford-nlp

I am using core nlp library to find coreference in my text

> Tyson lives in New York City with his wife and their two children.

when I am running this on [Stanford CoreNLP Online demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process) it's giving me correct [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yjdy.png)

but when I run this text on my machine it's returning null on this line of code

> Map graph = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class);

Thank you

Comment: Is there any problem with library as I have followed this code [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572207/stanford-core-nlp-understanding-coreference-resolution] and this code [https://github.com/drewfarris/corenlp-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/drew/corenlp/SimpleExample.java]. I don't know why it is giving me null on this text.

I tried this code [http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html] as well but it's throwing outofmemory exception, creating too many Hash tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this complete example - http://blog.pengyifan.com/resolve-coreference-using-stanford-corenlp/. I guess you are missing something as i am unable to understand the exact reason from the code you provided.